# Google sheets "ctrl+;" enters tomorrows date?

Tags: date, google-sheets, time, timezone, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been using the shortcut "Ctrl + ;" to enter todays date but all of the sudden it thinks the date is tomorrow? Where does google sheets get this date information and how can I correct it?

Comment: File>Spreadsheet Settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see spreadsheet settings:

[image]

.....